# Is it possible to craft a CSS selector to choose any of multiple possible identifiers?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got some CSS that is much bulkier than it seems to need to be and I'd like to know if there is a way to condense it down by writing selectors that will pick from multiple identifiers.

Here is an example:

```
.scrollbar.horizontal:hover .button
{
}
.scrollbar.horizontal:active .button
{
}
```

That I'd like to condense to something like:

```
.scrollbar.horizontal:(active|hover) .button
{
}
```

Is there a syntax that would allow this?

Comment: `.scrollbar.horizontal:hover .button, .scrollbar.horizontal:active .button {}` ?

Comment: Use the comma to list selectors then you can write the rules once for all of them as @DCoder suggested

Comment: Selectors 4 has [`:matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) but it is not implemented yet: `.scrollbar.horizontal:matches(:active, :hover) .button`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you find that joining the selectors together is a solution, no, not really:

```
.scrollbar.horizontal:hover .button, 
.scrollbar.horizontal:active .button {

}
```

Using a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS can clean it up:

```
.scrollbar.horizontal {
    &:hover, &:active {
        .button {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes when it allows me to.